# Can I apply scoping to GWT CSS obfuscated class-names

Tags: css, gwt

I have 2 CSS files defining 2 sets of CSS rules for the same CSSResource. Can I somehow apply some-sort of scope so that the styles from one css file don't override the styles from the other css file?

A simplified Example:

**CSSResource**

```
public interface Style extends CssResource {
String box_bkg();
}
```

**Style1.CSS**

```
.box_bkg {
background-color: red;
}
```

**Style2.CSS**

```
.box_bkg {
background-color: yellow;
}
```

**ClientBundle**

```
public interface BoxBundle extends ClientBundle {
    @Source("css/Style1.css")
    MyClass.Style redBoxStyle();

    @Source("css/Style2.css")
    MyClass.Style yellowBoxStyle();
}
```

When I look at the HTML generated, I see that the obfuscated class-name is the same regardless of which BoxBundle method it came from.  So the boxes are either all yellow or red.  How can I style the boxes differently if the obfuscated name is the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obfuscated class names are computed from the `CssResource` sub-interface and method names. If you want different class names, you have to make at least one subinterface of `MyClass.Style` and use it as the return type for the method(s) in `BoxBundle`; the goal is that the two methods have different return types:

```
public interface BoxBundle extends ClientBundle {
   @Source("css/Style1.css")
   Style1 redBoxStyle();

   @Source("css/Style2.css")
   Style2 yellowBoxStyle();

   interface Style1 extends MyClass.Style { }
   interface Style2 extends MyClass.Style { }
}
```

See also https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6144

Comment: That worked fine... luckily I just need 2 variants - Thanks :-)